# I want to display the cause in a panel and a label or listbox with date and km when my my computer date will be (date-before_day)

Tags: c#, mysql

[this is my reminder(MySQL) table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zd9px.png), I want to display the cause in a panel and a label or listbox with date and km when my my computer date will be (date-before_day)

```
void show_reminder()
    {
        string date = string.Empty;
        string cause = string.Empty;
        string t = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd");
        string t1 = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd");
        int km, km_now, before_day, today_date, rem_date = 0;
        today_date = Convert.ToInt32(t);

        string myConnection = "datasource= localhost;port=3306;username=root;password=root";
        MySqlConnection myConn = new MySqlConnection(myConnection);
        MySqlCommand SelectCommand = new MySqlCommand("select * from bs.reminder  ", myConn);//where date='" + t1 + "'
        MySqlDataReader myReader;
        myConn.Open();

        myReader = SelectCommand.ExecuteReader();
        while (myReader.Read())
        {

            date = DateTime.Parse(myReader.GetString(2)).ToString("yyyyMMdd");
            km = myReader.GetInt32(3);
            before_day = myReader.GetInt32(4);
            rem_date = Convert.ToInt32(date);
            km_now = Convert.ToInt32(label66.Text);


                if (today_date >= rem_date - before_day)
                {
                   cause = myReader.GetString(1);

                    listView1.Items.Add(cause);
                    panel10.Visible = true;



                }

                else if (km_now >= km)
                {
                    panel10.Visible = true;
                }
                else
                    panel10.Visible = false;

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First:** About getting the right records:

Not sure just which day you want to display. Here are 1 Day Before and After a given date dt as MySQL compatible strings:

```
string sDateBefore = dt.AddDays(-1).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
string sDateAfter  = dt.AddDays( 1).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

So assuming you want tomorrow's reminder records you could write:

```
string sTomorrow  = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

And your select could be

```
MySqlCommand SelectCommand = new MySqlCommand(
   "SELECT * FROM bs.reminder WHERE date = '" + sTomorrow  + "';", myConn);
```

I assume you want to use your `before_day` field in the calculation. Here is how to do that:

```
MySqlCommand SelectCommand = new MySqlCommand(
   "SELECT * FROM bs.reminder " 
+ " WHERE From_Days( To_Days( date ) - before_day ) = '" + sTomorrow  + "';", myConn);
```

As usual one should spend a little time on the dangers of `SQL Injection` and consider using parameters; but with the way the string is created, I don't see any problem here..

(..which is, of course, one of the most famous last words.)

**Second:** About Panels and displaying result Sets

You want to display a 'cause', which looks like a string field. You can't (easily) use a `Panel` for that. You could use a `Label` (with autosize turned off and size the way you want) or, more likely, a `TextBox`, probably with `MultiLine` enabled.

You can use a `Panel` for grouping the fields together, though.

If you expect several reminder records you could use a `ListView` or a `ListBox` and script the `SelectionChanged` event to show the details. If you add the records to `Listbox` you should consider creating a Reminder `Class` which could then include a custom ToString() method. When you add instances of that class to the `ListBox` it will display it nicely and you still can cast the select `Item` to Reminder and use all fields of your record.

And obviously there is also the `DataGridview`, which is made to display large Result Sets..

Comment: i am unable to understand...
SELECT* FROM bs.reminder " 
+ " WHERE From_Days( To_Days( date ) - before_day ) = '" + sTomorrow  + "';", myConn);

Comment: Well, you should learn about the two MySql function it uses:[To_Days](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_to-days) and [From_Days](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-days) ! This is probably the heart of your question! They convert a Date to an integer number and back. Inbetween you add (or subtract) the `before_day` number to the int. That is how to calculate a date in the future or past.

Comment: thanks ,i got it

but problem is that, suppose on 9/06/14 there have three cause, so how i display full rows individually?

Comment: either add columns (subitems) to your listview or put them into a datagridview! that's what they are for.

Comment: i use listview and use this...

cause = myReader.GetString(2);
listView1.Items.Add(cause);
but i want to display km and date relatively,so how i use the subitem, if posiible plz give the code for that. thanks.

Comment: Prepare by setting the View to Details and adding Columns as needed: listView1.View = View.Details;
    listView1.Columns.Add("Cause");
    listView1.Columns.Add("km");  
Then in your loop add each item in this format, which will give you back a handle: 
    ListViewItem lvi = listView1.Items.Add(cause);
..and finally add subitems to the ListViewItem as needed..:
    lvi.SubItems.Add(km);

Comment: Sir, i want to diplay the cause with date and km in idividual/separately  form, like a sticky note. can it possible? plz help me for that.

Comment: Sure. You can put a few Labels onto a Yellow Panel. You fill them in the ListView's SelectionIdexChanged event from the Items/Subitems. Give it a try. When you run into trouble create a new Question with the code that you can't get to work..

Comment: so i want to display the cause row in a new form f2 when datetime now is (day- before_day).suppose in reminder_id 1, their date is 2016/06/05 and before_day is 2. so i want to display the "servicing" when my computer date will be 2016/06/03 because(2016/06/05 - 2) it continue till 2016/06/05 and it stop when computer date will be 2016/06/06